# Recursive program never enters recursion?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to build a recursive program that prints all arrays of size `length` composed of the elements in `symbols`. I push the results into `$pos`.

```
def h(seq, symbols, length)
  if seq.length == length
    $pos << seq
  elsif symbols.empty?
    nil
  else
    h(seq << symbols[0], symbols, length)
    h(seq, symbols[1..-1], length)
  end
end
```

I ran it with `length = 3` and `symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c']` as follows:

```
symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
length = 3
seq = []
h(seq, symbols, length)
$pos
```

The output is:

```
[["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"]]
```

How does this happen, and where is the fault in my logic?

Comment: Take a look at the methods `Array.combination()`, `Array.permutation()`, `Array.repeated_combination()`, `Array.repeated_permutation()`. They might solve the problem your trying to solve in an easier way.

Comment: just a stylistic thing but I'd put `seq` as the last argument, then you do not need to pass it in the initial call to `h`, just change the method signature to `h(symbols, length, seq = [])`.

Comment: @JoshVoigts I wrote the logic in ruby because it's easy to avoid thinking about variable types and what not; I'm planning to write this in C++ after I get the correct logic

Comment: Also using `$pos` seems odd, because it is global.

Comment: @Kris probably just a shortcut to avoid returns / have it available in all levels of the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, okay, I'll play along.

As you can check on [my repl.it](https://repl.it/@jgabzdyl/MeagerIdolizedNumber), I used exactly your code, just added two "puts". I ran it with the same parameters as you.

```
h([], ["a", "b", "c"], 3)
> first
> first
> first
> second
> second
> second
=> [["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"]]
```

For explanation what this causes we need to look at this part of your code:

```
else
  h(seq << symbols[0], symbols, length)
  h(seq, symbols[1..-1], length)
end
```

You always call `h << seq symbols[0]` in your execution. This always puts "a" in your seq variable. Once you have three characters in your seq, you append it for the first time. Thanks to the if else structure of your script, the execution of this level of the function ends.

Then you call `h(seq, symbols[1..-1], length)` again. The problem here is, that you already have `seq.length == 3`, so you just append it again and end the execution of the function.

Then again, you call `h(seq, symbols[1..-1], length)`, you get the idea.

So, that is the fault of your logic explained.

I won't code this for you, but hopefully this explains where the fault is.

> Hint: you could use seq.dup as the parameter for both these functions, as this will do what it would in C. However, this also won't work as you expect it to thanks to `symbols[1..-1]` eliminating "a" from the permutation.